# Why transition_post_type hook is called twice for the same post?

Tags: php, functions, hooks, post-status

I need to do a curl request every time a new post is created.

In order to achieve that, i used the following code, very similar to the [one provided in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions).

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'wpse120996_do_curl', 10, 3);
function wpse120996_do_curl($new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
    $post_ID = $post->ID;
    error_log(" [ ". date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . " ] ". $post_ID . " : " .
    $old_status . " -> " . $new_status . "\n", 3, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/log.txt");

    if ($post->post_type != 'post' || $new_status != 'publish' || $old_status != 'draft') {
       return;
    }

    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/sendMessage';
    // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();
    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
          CURLOPT_URL => $url,
          CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
          CURLOPT_POST => 1,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
              chat_id => '@mychatid',
              text => print_r($post, true)
          )
      ));
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    error_log(" [ ". date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . " ] sending post with ID = ". $post_ID ."\n", 3, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/log.txt");
    if (!curl_exec($curl)) {
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    }
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

The problem is that *wpse120996_do_curl()* is called twice every time a post is saved, as you can see in the following screenshot.
[image]

How can i get only one function call when a post is saved?

I'm running this code in Wordpress 4.8.2 with no plugin installed.

Edit: after adding error_log() to the code, looking into log.txt, it seems that 
*wpse120996_do_curl()* is called only once, but unfortunately two curl request are done.

```
 log.txt content

 [ 2017-10-13 16:31:31 ] 109 : new -> auto-draft
 [ 2017-10-13 16:31:37 ] 109 : auto-draft -> draft
 [ 2017-10-13 16:32:05 ] 109 : draft -> publish
 [ 2017-10-13 16:32:05 ] sending post with ID = 109
 [ 2017-10-13 16:32:06 ] 110 : new -> inherit
```

Comment: you can try this action : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

Comment: @mmm already tried, same result unfortunately.

Comment: you can add a meta value like "alreadySendToTelegram" and test this meta to known if the code must send it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
if ($old_status != 'draft' || $new_status != 'publish') {
```

with:

```
if ( $post->post_type != 'post' || $new_status != 'publish' || $old_status != 'auto-draft' ) {
```

You want to run your code on `post` transition from `auto-draft` to `publish`, which will occur once only, when your `post` is created.

**UPDATE**

The problem is in this part of your code:

```
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
error_log(" [ ". date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . " ] sending post with ID = ". $post_ID ."\n", 3, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/log.txt");
if (!curl_exec($curl)) {
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}
```

You are calling `curl_exec($curl)` in two lines! First:

```
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

and second:

```
if (!curl_exec($curl)) {
```

Change your `if` statement to:

```
if (!$resp) {
```

Comment: i updated my code according to your suggestions. Looking into log.txt content, it seems that *wpse120996_do_curl()* is called only once, but i got two telegram messages yet. I can't figure out why two curl requests are made.

Comment: @DarioCapozzi please read my updated answer.